# Make the record seperator in AWK not apply after the last record?

Tags: awk

I change `ORS` to be `,`. I find that the record separator applies after the last output record. Is there any way to make it not apply to the last output record?

Similarly. does `OFS` also apply to the last field? If yes, can I make it not?

Answer (score 8):

There are couple tricks.

One is, not using build-in ORS.

For example instead of

```
$ seq 5 | awk -v ORS=",\n" '{print $0}'
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
```

do this

```
$ seq 5 | awk '{printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=",\n"} END{print ""}'
1,
2,
3,
4,
5
```

Another trick is removing the last new line from the input file and use RT as a proxy (might be gawk only)

```
$ seq 5 | head -c -1 | awk -v ORS=",\n" '{printf "%s%s",$0,RT?ORS:""}'
1,
2,
3,
4,
5   # <-- no newline here but you can add in the END block.
```

For OFS you can do something similar.

```
$ paste <(seq 5) <(seq 11 15) 
  | awk -v OFS=, '{sep=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s",sep $i*$i; sep=OFS} printf "\n"}'

1,121
4,144
9,169
16,196
25,225
```

Note that if you're not constructing the line in a loop, just adding the fields separated by comma will solve the problem. e.g. `print $1*$1, $2*$2`

Comment: Since when is the output records separator by default `,\n` ?

Comment: Who says it's the default?  It's set as an example to show the effect.  If it were the default you don't need to set them anyway.

Comment: I am very sorry! I read the question again. It was my fault! +1

Comment: Thanks. I check if  `OFS` applies after the last field, by `echo "a b c" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","}; {$1=$1;print $0};'`. The output is `a,b,c`, not `a,b,c,`. It seems that it doesn't apply after the last field, correct? So does "seperator" mean differently for records and for fields?

Comment: Yes, unless you construct the record in a loop by adding a field and OFS, the last field won't have an OFS attached.