# Why does removing `END{print ""}` not print the last line?

Tags: awk

I am reading an example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34685332/156458

```
$ seq 5 | awk '{printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=",\n"} END{print ""}'
1,
2,
3,
4,
5
```

I thought `END{print ""}` is superfluous, so

```
$ seq 5 | awk '{printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=",\n"} '
1,
2,
3,
4,
```

Why does removing `END{print ""}` not print the last line?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're removing `{print ""}` which effectively prints a new line.

the `5` should appear just before your prompt, but your shell may not allow that and just drops it all together.

`$ seq 5 | awk '{printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=",\n"} END{print ""}'` prints:

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
5
$>
```

and `$ seq 5 | awk '{printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=",\n"}` prints:

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
5$>
```

Comment: Why doesn't `{printf "%s%s",sep,$0; sep=",\n"}` print the last line?

Answer (score 2):

how about making it simpler:

```
seq 5 | awk -v RS="\0" -v OFS=",\n" '{$1=$1}7'
```

Comment: This is actually a great answer for the referenced question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684958/make-the-record-seperator-in-awk-not-apply-after-the-last-record/34685332#34685332