# Replace newline \n with expression using sed (or awk, or tr)

Tags: awk, sed, grep, tr

I'm trying to clean up the syntax of a pseudo-json file. The file is too large to open in a text editor (20 gb), so I have to do all of this via command line (running Arch linux). The one thing I cannot figure out how to do is replace new line characters in sed (GNU sed v. 4.8)

Specifically I have data of the form:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "value" : 2
}
{
    "id" : 2,
    "value" : 4
}
```

And I need to put a comma after the closed curly bracket (but not the last one). So I want the output to looks like:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "value" : 2
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "value" : 4
}
```

Ideally I'd just do this in `sed`, but from reading about this, sed flattens the text first, so it's not clear how to replace newline characters.
Ideally I'd just run something like `sed 's/}\n{/},\n{/g' test.json`, but this doesn't work (nor does using \\n in place of \n).

I've also tried awk, but have run into similar issue of not being able to replace the combination of a hard return with brackets. And I can get tr to replace the hard returns, but not the combination of characters.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, by default `sed` works line by line. You cannot match across multiple lines unless you use features to bring in multiple lines to the pattern space. Here's one way to do it, provided the input strictly follows the sample shown:

```sh
sed '/}$/{N; s/}\n{/},\n{/}' ip.txt
```

- `/}$/` match `}` at the end of a line

  - `{}` allows you to group commands to be executed for a particular address
  - `N` will add the next line to the pattern space
  - `s/}\n{/},\n{/` perform the required substitution
- Use `-i` option for in-place editing

This solution can fail for sequences like shown below, but I assume two lines ending with `}` will not occur in a row.

```
}
}
{
abc
}
```

Use `sed '/}$/{N; s/}\n{/},\n{/; P; D}'` if the above sequence can occur.

Comment: This works great. The one thing to note is that character encoding also seems to matter. I had to re-encode the file as ascii to get this to work.

Comment: @user3037237 probably worth it to ask your encoding issue on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ (it might work with appropriate locale setting too)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` program; using `RS` and setting its value to null then simply apply `gsub`(Global substitution) to substitute from `}\n{` to `},\n{` in matches.

```
awk -v RS= '{gsub(/}\n{/,"},\n{")} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: That's not a good idea for 20 gb file if there are no paragraphs

Answer (score 1):

You can used GNU sed for `-z` to do that:

```
$ sed -z 's/}\n{/},\n{/g' file
{
    "id" : 1,
    "value" : 2
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "value" : 4
}
```

but then it's non-portable, has to read the whole file into memory at once, and is hard to adapt if the file format isn't exactly as you expect (e.g. additional spaces, comment lines, etc.) or you need to make any additional adjustments.

I'd just use awk, e.g. using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk 'NR>1{print prev (prev=="}" ? "," : "")} {prev=$0} END{print prev}' file
{
    "id" : 1,
    "value" : 2
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "value" : 4
}
```

That would be portable across all Unix boxes, just reads 1 line at a time so uses almost no memory, and would be trivial to adapt for any differences in your input or additional changes you want made to the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "value" : 2
}
{
    "id" : 2,
    "value" : 4
}
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="}\n{"}{printf "%s%s",sep,$0;sep="},\n{"}' file.txt
```

output

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "value" : 2
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "value" : 4
}
```

Explanation: I used `RS` (row seperator) to split on `}\n{` then I do not use `ORS` as this would result in trailing `ORS`, I use trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684958/make-the-record-seperator-in-awk-not-apply-after-the-last-record).

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

When the last `}` is on the last line, you can tell  `sed` to skip the replacement on last line

```
sed '$ !s/}/},/' test.json
```